# Script de dias úteis

Tags: php

Estou usando um script que encontrei [nesta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23444968/how-can-i-calculate-the-number-of-working-days-between-two-dates) do SOen, e para contar os dias úteis desconsiderando sábado e domingo (dá pra fazer só com domingo tbm, alterando `$what_day > 5` para `$what_day > 6` por exemplo) ele funciona certinho, mas eu queria incluir o calendário oficial de feriados do Brasil.

Este é o script que está funcionando (já pegando os dados do meu formulário):

```
    <?php
//get current month for example
$beginday = ($_POST ["Tdesl"]);
$lastday  = ($_POST ["Tinsem3"]);

$nr_work_days = getWorkingDays($beginday, $lastday);
echo $nr_work_days;

function getWorkingDays($startDate, $endDate)
{
    $begin = strtotime($startDate);
    $end   = strtotime($endDate);
    if ($begin > $end) {
        echo "startdate is in the future! <br />";

        return 0;
    } else {
        $no_days  = 0;
        $weekends = 0;
        while ($begin <= $end) {
            $no_days++; // no of days in the given interval
            $what_day = date("N", $begin);
            if ($what_day > 5) { // 6 and 7 are weekend days
                $weekends++;
            };
            $begin += 86400; // +1 day
        };
        $working_days = $no_days - $weekends;

        return $working_days;
    }
}
```

O HTML:

```
<form method="post" id="Cform" name="Tform" action="diasuteis2.php">
    <label for="Cinsem">Data inicial:</label>
    <input type="date" name="Tinsem3" id="Cinsem" size="6">
    <label for="Cdesl22">Data final:</label>
    <input type="date" name="Tdesl" id="Cdesl22" size="6"><br><br>
    <p align="center">
    <input type="submit" id="enviar"></p>
</form>
```

Um exemplo de saída correta para:

```
echo $beginday;
echo "<br><br>";
echo $lastday;
echo "<br><br>";
echo $nr_work_days;
```

É:

> 2014-12-10
>
> 2014-12-15
>
> 4

(Ele considerou o dia 10, e excluiu os dias 13 e 14 corretamente)

É possível, ou viável, incluir os feriados neste código? Se alguém puder fazer um exemplo (claro que não precisa incluir todos os feriados, apenas mostrar como posso fazer isso) agradeço desde já.

Comment: Basicamente precisa ter uma lista, um array com datas de feriados. Sugiro que evite definir Sábado e Domingo como dias "não úteis" pois nem sempre é assim. Restaurantes, por exemplo, vendem mais nos fins de semana e geralmente folgam em dia de semana quando tem baixo movimento. Para esses, Sábado e Domingo são dias úteis. Quanto a feriados, também precisa avaliar os feriados regionais e municipais tal como feriados sem data definida. Precisa concentrar-se mais na lógica dos feriados para então poder brincar com o calendário. Claro, que isso tudo se vc quiser tornar o script reaproveitável.

Comment: Achei um package interessante a partir de uma pesquisa rápida. Porém é preciso definir os feriados via array https://github.com/ministryofjustice/date-utils

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Deixo aqui um exemplo para contagem dos feriados. Atenção que isto não foi testado, por isso pode ter algum erro.

```
function getWorkingDays($startDate, $endDate) {
    $begin = strtotime($startDate);
    $end   = strtotime($endDate);
    if ($begin > $end) {
        echo "startdate is in the future! <br />";
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        $holidays = array('01/01', '25/12', ...);
        $weekends = 0;
        $no_days = 0;
        $holidayCount = 0;
        while ($begin <= $end) {
            $no_days++; // no of days in the given interval
            if (in_array(date("d/m", $begin), $holidays)) {
                $holidayCount++;
            }
            $what_day = date("N", $begin);
            if ($what_day > 5) { // 6 and 7 are weekend days
                $weekends++;
            };
            $begin += 86400; // +1 day
        };
        $working_days = $no_days - $weekends - $holidayCount;

        return $working_days;
    }
}
```

Comment: Está dando uma pequena diferença de um dia para esta calculadora de dias úteis online http://www.dias-uteis.com/ quando coloco as datas entre 01/01/2015 e 31/12/2015, mas acho que é porque o script não está considerando o dia final no cálculo, ou pode ser um erro na calculadora on line (depois vou verificar manualmente a quantidade de dias úteis). De qualquer forma funcionou perfeitamente, se quiser incluir os outros feriados nacionais na resposta, fica assim: `$holidays = array('01/01', '03/04', '21/04', '01/05', '07/09', '12/10', '02/11', '15/11', '25/12');`. Valeu!

Comment: Ah, outro pequeno detalhe foi que precisei inverter no form o dia de início e final, porque a ordem dos campos ficou invertida (a diferença dava sempre 0 quando colocava a data inicial e final nos campos respectivos, mas foi só inverter que funcionou perfeitamente). Mas isso foi simples, apenas pra constar aqui caso alguém venha utilizar o mesmo script.

Answer (score 3):

Gostaria de acrescentar sobre os feriados:

```
    function dias_feriados($ano = null)
    {
        if ($ano === null)
        {
            $ano = intval(date('Y'));
        }

        $pascoa     = easter_date($ano); // Limite de 1970 ou após 2037 da easter_date PHP consulta http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.easter-date.php
        $dia_pascoa = date('j', $pascoa);
        $mes_pascoa = date('n', $pascoa);
        $ano_pascoa = date('Y', $pascoa);

        $feriados = array(
            // Tatas Fixas dos feriados Nacionail Basileiras
            mktime(0, 0, 0, 1,  1,   $ano), // Confraternização Universal - Lei nº 662, de 06/04/49
            mktime(0, 0, 0, 4,  21,  $ano), // Tiradentes - Lei nº 662, de 06/04/49
            mktime(0, 0, 0, 5,  1,   $ano), // Dia do Trabalhador - Lei nº 662, de 06/04/49
            mktime(0, 0, 0, 9,  7,   $ano), // Dia da Independência - Lei nº 662, de 06/04/49
            mktime(0, 0, 0, 10,  12, $ano), // N. S. Aparecida - Lei nº 6802, de 30/06/80
            mktime(0, 0, 0, 11,  2,  $ano), // Todos os santos - Lei nº 662, de 06/04/49
            mktime(0, 0, 0, 11, 15,  $ano), // Proclamação da republica - Lei nº 662, de 06/04/49
            mktime(0, 0, 0, 12, 25,  $ano), // Natal - Lei nº 662, de 06/04/49

            // These days have a date depending on easter
            mktime(0, 0, 0, $mes_pascoa, $dia_pascoa - 48,  $ano_pascoa),//2ºferia Carnaval
            mktime(0, 0, 0, $mes_pascoa, $dia_pascoa - 47,  $ano_pascoa),//3ºferia Carnaval 
            mktime(0, 0, 0, $mes_pascoa, $dia_pascoa - 2 ,  $ano_pascoa),//6ºfeira Santa  
            mktime(0, 0, 0, $mes_pascoa, $dia_pascoa     ,  $ano_pascoa),//Pascoa
            mktime(0, 0, 0, $mes_pascoa, $dia_pascoa + 60,  $ano_pascoa),//Corpus Cirist
        );

        sort($feriados);

        return $feriados;
    }
```

Você indica o ano e ele gera um ARRAY com os dias dos feriados.
Fora isso ainda há feriados municipais que deveram ser adicionados ao ARRAY.
Particularmente eu coloquei em um banco de dados os feriados municipais, pois na equipe há pessoas trabalhando em várias localidades.

Para mostrar as datas:

```
            $feriados = dias_feriados();
            $diaf = count($feriados);
            for ($x=0;$x<$diaf;$x++){
                echo '<p>'.date('Y-m-d',$feriados[$x]).'</p>';
            }
```

Answer (score -3):

Como posso entender sua pergunta, você precisa obter a contagem de documentos anualmente ou mensalmente ou diariamente,

Você pode usar $ano 12, $mês 6, $diaOfMinth 26 Date Expression Operators.

Exemplo para a contagem diária de documentos,

[{
Grupo de dólares: {
_id: {
ano: {$ ano: "$seuDateFieldName" },
mês: {$mês: "$yourDateFieldName" },
dia: {DiaDiaMês: "$yourDateFieldName" }
},
Total: {US$sum: 1 }
}
}]
Exemplo para a contagem mensal de documentos [contagemdedias](https://contagemdedias.com.br/),

[{
Grupo de dólares: {
_id: {
ano: {$ ano: "$seuDateFieldName" },
mês: {$mês: "$yourDateFieldName" }
},
Total: {US$sum: 1 }
}
}]
Você pode substituir suaDateFieldName pelo seu campo de coleta e colocar sua etapa de $match antes desta etapa de $group.

Answer (score -3):

Bem basicão, espero que gostem:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_erros',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);


$date = '2023-06-09';
$days = 10; // são 10 dias úteis! Não são 10 dias corridos.
$dataPlanejada = addDayswithdate($date,$days);
echo $dataPlanejada;
exit;


function addDayswithdate($date,$days){
    $dataPlanejadaInvertida = '';

    $dateCalc = strtotime($date);

    // É para somar 'N' dias UTEIS e não somar 'N' dias corridos
    // Checar dia por dia, se é útil ou não.
    for($i=1; $i<= $days; $i++) {
        $dateCalc = strtotime("+1 days", $dateCalc);


        do {
            $flagRecheck = false;

            $weekday = date("D", $dateCalc);
            if ($weekday == 'Sat') {
                $dateCalc = strtotime("+1 days", $dateCalc);
                $dateCalc = strtotime("+1 days", $dateCalc);
                $flagRecheck = true;
            } else {
                if ($weekday == 'Sun') {
                    $dateCalc = strtotime("+1 days", $dateCalc);
                    $flagRecheck = true;
                } else {
                    $diaMes = date("d-m", $dateCalc);
                    // Feriado?
                    if (in_array($diaMes, array('01-01', '21-04', '01-05', '07-09', '12-10', '02-11', '15-11', '25-12'))) {
                        $dateCalc = strtotime("+1 days", $dateCalc);
                        $flagRecheck = true;
                    }
                }
            }

        } while ($flagRecheck == true); 


    }
    $dataPlanejadaInvertida .= date("Y-m-d", $dateCalc);
    return $dataPlanejadaInvertida ;
}
```