# Contagem de dias específicos da semana entre duas datas

Tags: php

Estou tentando apurar quantos dias específicos da semana existem entre dois períodos de tempo.

Como disse [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/61369/script-de-dias-%C3%BAteis), estou utilizando este script, adaptado com a ajuda [desta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/61375/23400), para conseguir os dias úteis, retirando sábados, domingos e feriados nacionais:

```
$beginday = isset($_POST["Tinsem3"]) ? $_POST["Tinsem3"] : false;
$lastday  = isset($_POST["Tdesl"]) ? $_POST["Tdesl"] : false;

$nr_work_days = getWorkingDays($beginday, $lastday);

function getWorkingDays($startDate, $endDate) {
    $begin = strtotime($startDate);
    $end   = strtotime($endDate);
    if ($begin > $end) {
        echo "startdate is in the future! <br />";
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        $holidays = array('01/01', '03/04', '21/04', '01/05', '07/09', '12/10', '02/11', '15/11', '25/12');
        $weekends = 0;
        $no_days = 0;
        $holidayCount = 0;
        while ($begin <= $end) {
            $no_days++; // no of days in the given interval
            if (in_array(date("d/m", $begin), $holidays)) {
                $holidayCount++;
            }
            $what_day = date("N", $begin);
            if ($what_day > 5) { // 6 and 7 are weekend days
                $weekends++;
            };
            $begin += 86400; // +1 day
        };
        $working_days = $no_days - $weekends - $holidayCount;

        return $working_days;
    }
}
```

Mas queria agora pegar quantos dias específicos da semana existem entre estes dois períodos. Tenho conhecimento bem básico de PHP, então uma boa explicação também seria bem vinda.

Sei que pra pegar apenas os dias específicos é apenas pegar a diferença e contar quantos dias da semana existem entre as datas (que não precisa deste script todo). Mas existe uma função específica pra isso?

Algo do tipo:

```
function getWednesDays($startDate, $endDate) {
$begin = strtotime($startDate);
$end   = strtotime($endDate);
$totaldequartasfeiras = XXX
```

Juntei o script porque preciso também que os feriados nacionais não sejam incluídos, então seria legal se desse pra "aproveitar" esta parte.

Answer (score 1):

Antes do while cria a seguinte variavel:

```
$array_semana = array();
```

E dentro do while logo após: `$begin += 86400; // +1 day`, insira:

```
$array_semana[$what_day]++;
```

Assim ao término do while você terá a quantidade de dias de cada dia da semana dentro do `$array_semana`

Comment: Então, fiz isso mas não funcionou. Um `var_dump` de `array_semana` retorna `NULL`. Será que não preciso incluir os nomes (ou abreviações pré-determinadas) dos dias da semana dentro de `array()`? Como ele vai retornar os dias específicos da semana apenas com `$array_semana[$what_day]++;`? Ainda sou iniciante em PHP, e agradeço a ajuda e as explicações.

Comment: dentro do $array_semana, ele irá armazenar a quantidade de dias da semana em cada indíce do array, por exemplo o indíce 1 do array_semana corresponde a quantidade de segundas feiras, o 2 terça, 3 quarta e assim sucessivamente. Mas uma pergunta `$array_semana[$what_day]++` voce colocou dentro do while e o var_dump após o while terminar?

Comment: Então, colocando o `var_dump` dentro do bloco `while` (bem após `$array_semana[$what_day]++;`), antes de `return`, então ele retorna `array(1) { [3]=> int(1) } array(2) { [3]=> int(1) [4]=> int(1) }` etc... mas o que eu quero é pegar cada dia da semana, contar quantos foram entre os períodos e jogar esses valores dentro de variáveis, como por exemplo: `array_segunda`, `array_terça`, ou dentro de vetores, `array_semana[1]` ser quantas segundas, `array_semana[2]` ser quantas terças, pra que eu possa usar estas variáveis (com a quantidade de dias) em cálculos etc... Valeu pela força.