# Como transformar saída do strotime em uma variável

Tags: php, variáveis, declaração-de-variável

Estou tentando usar [este script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7061802/php-function-for-get-all-mondays-within-date-range), que retorna todas as segundas-feiras entre dois períodos:

```
$beginday = isset($_POST["Tinsem3"]) ? $_POST["Tinsem3"] : false;
$lastday  = isset($_POST["Tdesl"]) ? $_POST["Tdesl"] : false;

$lastday = strtotime($lastday);
for($i = strtotime('Monday', strtotime($beginday)); $i <= $lastday; $i = strtotime('+1 week', $i))
    echo date('l Y-m-d', $i);
```

Adaptei pra buscar os dados do formulário, e a saída entre as datas `08/04/2015` e `08/05/2015` já é correta:

> Monday 2015-04-13
>
> Monday 2015-04-20
>
> Monday 2015-04-27
>
> Monday 2015-05-04

O que quero é colocar cada um desses resultados dentro de variáveis, pra poder contar quantas segundas existem e poder utilizar para fazer alguns cálculos.

Já tentei fazer algo como:

```
$tornararray = array (date('l Y-m-d', $i));
```

Pra depois contar as `arrays`, com algo tipo:

```
$total2 = count(array_filter($tornararray));
```

Mas quando dou `var_dump`de `$tornararray`, recebo a saída:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(17) "Monday 2015-05-04" }
```

Pelo que entendi, ele está pegando apenas a última ocorrência. Como faço para transformar cada um dos resultados que consigo com `echo date('l Y-m-d', $i);` em variáveis?

Warning: Esta pergunta **não é duplicata [desta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/63652/contagem-de-dias-espec%C3%ADficos-da-semana-entre-duas-datas)**. São dúvidas diferentes. Aqui quero saber como incluir os resultados (de um outro script, **não o utilizado naquela pergunta**) dentro de variáveis, enquanto naquele outro tenho objetivos bem diferentes (adaptar aquele script de dias úteis etc...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Desculpe se entendi errado, mas o que quer é isso?

```
$date = array();

for($i = strtotime('Monday', strtotime($beginday)); $i <= $lastday; $i = strtotime('+1 week', $i))
{
    $date[] = date('l Y-m-d', $i);
}

$total = count( $date );
```

Comment: Olá, dê uma olhada aqui [array_push()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-push.php).

Comment: Array_push: `Adiciona um ou mais elementos no final de um array`, e o que ele quer é `contar quantas segundas`. Basta criar um array e contar os índices.

Comment: `$array[] = $i` é equivalente a `array_push($array, $i)`. O primeiro ainda é mais rápido por não fazer chamada de função.

Comment: O que eu quis dizer, é que a tua resposta é praticamente igual a outra, simplesmente utilizaste a outra metodologia, e retornaste o valor na função `count()` :/ isso pode complicar a pessoa que fez a pergunta, e cria repostas duplicadas, creio que o mais correto seria `editar` a resposta acima, e acrescentar esses detalhes.

Answer (score 3):

```html
$arr = array();
for($i = strtotime('Monday', strtotime($beginday)); $i <= $lastday; $i = strtotime('+1 week', $i))
    array_push($arr, date('l Y-m-d', $i));

print_r($arr);
```

Comment: Só um adendo: array_push tem o mesmo efeito de `$array[] = $var` - vide o manual!

Comment: Sim. É verdade, @Papa Charlie. É até mesmo melhor fazer isso, por causa do pré-processamento.

Comment: Sim, e no final você terá que usar `count` pra contar os itens - é inevitavel

Comment: Testei aqui e as duas soluções funcionaram! +1 Dei como resolvido na do @PapaCharlie por ter incluído já a contagem. Valeu a ambos!