# Cálculo de dias úteis

Tags: php, laravel

Galera, eu tenho alguns métodos em PHP que me retornam a quantidade de dias entre a data inicial e a data final, porém, gostaria de receber como parâmetro, apenas data inicial e quantidade de dias e receber depois, o dia final

```
public function index()
{
    $yDataInicial = date('d/m/Y'); 
    $yDataFinal = '28/04/2019';

    $diaFDS = 0; //dias não úteis(Sábado=6 Domingo=0)
    $calculoDias = $this->CalculaDias($yDataInicial, $yDataFinal); //número de dias entre a data inicial e a final
    $diasUteis = 0;

    while($yDataInicial != $yDataFinal){
        $diaSemana = date("w", $this->dataToTimestamp($yDataInicial)); 
        if($diaSemana == 0 || $diaSemana == 6){ 
            //se SABADO OU DOMINGO, SOMA 01
            $diaFDS++;
        }else{
        //senão vemos se este dia é FERIADO
            for($i=0; $i<=12; $i++){
                if($yDataInicial == $this->Feriados(date("Y"),$i)){
                $diaFDS++;   
                }
            }
        }
        $yDataInicial = $this->Soma1dia($yDataInicial); //dia + 1
    }
    $final =  $calculoDias - $diaFDS;
    return view('welcome', compact('final'));
}



public function CalculaDias($xDataInicial, $xDataFinal)
{
    $time1 = $this->dataToTimestamp($xDataInicial);  
    $time2 = $this->dataToTimestamp($xDataFinal);  

    $tMaior = $time1 > $time2 ? $time1 : $time2;  
    $tMenor = $time1 < $time2 ? $time1 : $time2;  
    $diff = $tMaior-$tMenor;  
    $numDias = $diff/86400; //86400 é o número de segundos que 1 dia possui  
    return $numDias; // dias corridos     
}


public function dataToTimestamp($data)
{
    $ano = substr($data, 6,4);
    $mes = substr($data, 3,2);
    $dia = substr($data, 0,2);
    return mktime(0, 0, 0, $mes, $dia, $ano);
}

public function feriados($ano,$posicao) 
{
    $dia = 86400;
    $datas = array();
    $datas['pascoa'] = easter_date($ano);
    $datas['sexta_santa'] = $datas['pascoa'] - (2 * $dia);
    $datas['carnaval'] = $datas['pascoa'] - (47 * $dia);
    $datas['corpus_cristi'] = $datas['pascoa'] + (60 * $dia);
    $feriados = array (
        '01/01',
        '02/02', // Navegantes
        date('d/m',$datas['carnaval']),
        date('d/m',$datas['sexta_santa']),
        date('d/m',$datas['pascoa']),
        '21/04',
        '01/05',
        date('d/m',$datas['corpus_cristi']),
        '20/09', // Revolução Farroupilha \m/
        '12/10',
        '02/11',
        '15/11',
        '25/12',
    );

    return $feriados[$posicao]."/".$ano;
}

public function Soma1dia($data){   
    $ano = substr($data, 6,4);
    $mes = substr($data, 3,2);
    $dia = substr($data, 0,2);
    return   date("d/m/Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, $mes, $dia+1, $ano));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veja se é o que você quer, vai pegar os dias úteis, a quantidade e o último dia. A partir de uma data inicial e dentro de uma quantidade de dias.

```
<?php

function getListaDiasFeriado($ano = null) {

    if ($ano === null) {
        $ano = intval(date('Y'));
    }

    $pascoa = easter_date($ano); // retorna data da pascoa do ano especificado
    $diaPascoa = date('j', $pascoa);
    $mesPacoa = date('n', $pascoa);
    $anoPascoa = date('Y', $pascoa);

    $feriados = [
        // Feriados nacionais fixos
        mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, $ano),   // Confraternização Universal
        mktime(0, 0, 0, 4, 21, $ano),  // Tiradentes
        mktime(0, 0, 0, 5, 1, $ano),   // Dia do Trabalhador
        mktime(0, 0, 0, 9, 7, $ano),   // Dia da Independência
        mktime(0, 0, 0, 10, 12, $ano), // N. S. Aparecida
        mktime(0, 0, 0, 11, 2, $ano),  // Todos os santos
        mktime(0, 0, 0, 11, 15, $ano), // Proclamação da republica
        mktime(0, 0, 0, 12, 25, $ano), // Natal
        //
        // Feriados variaveis
        mktime(0, 0, 0, $mesPacoa, $diaPascoa - 48, $anoPascoa), // 2º feria Carnaval
        mktime(0, 0, 0, $mesPacoa, $diaPascoa - 47, $anoPascoa), // 3º feria Carnaval 
        mktime(0, 0, 0, $mesPacoa, $diaPascoa - 2, $anoPascoa),  // 6º feira Santa  
        mktime(0, 0, 0, $mesPacoa, $diaPascoa, $anoPascoa),      // Pascoa
        mktime(0, 0, 0, $mesPacoa, $diaPascoa + 60, $anoPascoa), // Corpus Christ
    ];

    sort($feriados);

    $listaDiasFeriado = [];
    foreach ($feriados as $feriado) {
        $data = date('Y-m-d', $feriado);
        $listaDiasFeriado[$data] = $data;
    }

    return $listaDiasFeriado;
}

function isFeriado($data) {
    $listaFeriado = getListaDiasFeriado(date('Y', strtotime($data)));
    if (isset($listaFeriado[$data])) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

function getDiasUteis($aPartirDe, $quantidadeDeDias = 30) {
    $dateTime = new DateTime($aPartirDe);

    $listaDiasUteis = [];
    $contador = 0;
    while ($contador < $quantidadeDeDias) {
        $dateTime->modify('+1 weekday'); // adiciona um dia pulando finais de semana
        $data = $dateTime->format('Y-m-d');
        if (!isFeriado($data)) {
            $listaDiasUteis[] = $data;
            $contador++;
        }
    }

    return $listaDiasUteis;
}

$listaDiasUteis = getDiasUteis("2019-04-17", 15);
$ultimoDia = end($listaDiasUteis);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($listaDiasUteis);
echo "</pre>";

echo "ULTIMO DIA: " . $ultimoDia;
```

Função de calculo do feriado retirada [daqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/61369/script-de-dias-%C3%BAteis).

Veja funcionando [aqui](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/363eaa72fe16722300f73d7dd2ced8ec81469551)

Comment: Muito obrigado por responder, achei bom seu código, testei aqui, muito bom, porém, vou te dar um exemplo, imaginando que a data inicial seja hoje dia 17/04/2019, determinei a quantidade de dias corridos 15, a data final deveria ser dia 08/05/2019, ou seja, seu código esta ótimo mas ele está contando finais de semana e feriados tbm, como poderia tirar fora os finais de semanas e feriados, obrigado....

Comment: data inicial 17/04/2019, resultado : ["18\/04\/2019","19\/04\/2019","22\/04\/2019","23\/04\/2019","24\/04\/2019","25\/04\/2019","26\/04\/2019","29\/04\/2019","30\/04\/2019","01\/05\/2019","02\/05\/2019"] preciso tirar finais de semana e feriados, e o resultado tem que ser dia 08/05/2019

Comment: Bem, fazendo testes, consegui resolver parte do problema, só fiz inserir dentro do IF o contador ...  
if ($numDiaDaSemana != 0 && $numDiaDaSemana != 6) { // se não for sabado e nem domingo 
     $listaDiasUteis[] = $dateTime->format('d/m/Y');
     $contador++;
}
assim ele me traz a data final e retirou realmente os finais de semana, vou tentar criar uma função para remover os feriados agora, obrigado amigo, ajudou ....

Comment: @RafaelMoura nesse caso basta alterar a linha $dateTime->modify('+1 day') por $dateTime->modify('+1 weekday') 
e ele já incrementa sem considerar os finais de semana. Alterei, da uma olhada.

Comment: mas ele fica sem o contador mesmo Diego ?

Comment: pq eu tirei o contato++ e ele não opera nada

Comment: e outra coisa, weekday com o contador fora do IF, colocando datainicio = 17/04/2019 e 8 dias, ele mostrar o resultado a partir do dia 23\/04\/2019 até o final 11\/06\/2019

Comment: Coloquei a função do feriado também, pode copiar tudo e substituir. Colocando 17/04 deve vir 08/05, certo?

Comment: deixa eu ver aqui , 1 minuto

Comment: sabe o que é curioso, se eu colocar "+1 day weekday" com o contador dentro do IF, ele começa a contar do dia 23\/04\/2019", e isso eu coloquei o dia de hoje com quantidaDias = 8, acho que o weekday naõ se aplica aqui

Comment: começando hoje, tirando o weekday e quantiDia = 8, dá certo olha o resultado ["18\/04\/2019","19\/04\/2019","22\/04\/2019","23\/04\/2019","24\/04\/2019","25\/04\/2019","26\/04\/2019","29\/04\/2019"]

Comment: @RafaelMoura a sintaxe é $dateTime->modify('+1 weekday'); e não $dateTime->modify('+1 day weekday');

Comment: verdade, que falta de atenção, funcionou agora ....

Comment: esta função de feriado no primeiro código que enviei, que tem parâmetros $ano e $posição se aplica, ou vc tem um específico, por gentileza .... ?

Comment: @RafaelMoura acrescei a função de calculo de feriado, da uma olhada.

Comment: Você é um gênio, agora está tudo ok, salvou meu dia, muito bom, obrigadíssimo mesmo, espero que a comunidade aproveite o código, obrigado.

Comment: @RafaelMoura Que bom que deu certo! Abs