# Calculando dias úteis a uma data!

Tags: php, data, lógica

Estou fazendo um sistema de retirada de produtos, por exemplo:
Determinada categoria de produto tem X dias úteis para ser retirado.

Categoria | Dias úteis
1          | 1
2 | 3
3 | 4
4 | 3
5 | 3
6 | 3
7 | 4

Por exemplo, hoje é dia 22/05/2019 Quarta-Feira:
Se eu pegar um produto com categoria 7 são + 4 dias úteis, no caso a entrega a partir do dia 28/05/2019.

com essa function o que eu consigo fazer é caso a data de entrega caia em um fim de semana, ela empurra a data para o próximo dia útil... mas está errado..

```
function verificaFinalSemana($data){
// sabado = 6
// domingo = 0
if(date('w', strtotime($data)) == 6 || date('w', strtotime($data)) == 0){
    $nova_data = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data . "+1 day"));
    verificaFinalSemana($nova_data);
}else{;
    $nova_data = $data;
}
return date('d/m/Y', strtotime($nova_data));
}
```

Como faço pra resolver isso?

Um agravante é, o sistema que eu estou mexendo é PHP 4.

Grato!

Comment: Dá uma olhada em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/61369/script-de-dias-%C3%BAteis